# Gstreamerで音声のG.722のエンコード/デコードをしようとしています

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Gstreamerで音声のG.722のエンコード/デコードをしたくて今以下の簡単なパイプラインで動作の確認をしているのですがデコードがうまく行きません
何が問題なのかわかる方がいれば教えていただけないでしょうか

・エンコード(audiotestsrcをG722にしてみる)

```
$gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! avenc_g722 ! filesink location=audio.g722
```

→パイプラインは動作問題なく動作していそう
　生成されたaudio.g722はffplayで再生ができる

・デコード(エンコードで生成されたファイルをデコードしてみるが動作しない)

```
$gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=audio.g722 ! avdec_g722 ! filesink location=audio.raw
```

→内部データフローエラーが発生する(以下にログ)

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=audio.g722 ! avdec_g722 ! filesink location=audio.raw
パイプラインを一時停止 (PAUSED) にしています...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0: 内部データフローエラー
追加のデバッグ情報:
gstbasesrc.c(2948): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0:
streaming task paused, reason error (-5)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

デコードは何が問題なのでしょうか？

```
$gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! avenc_g722 ! avdec_g722 ! autoaudiosink
```

このパイプラインでaudiotestsrcにavenc_g722と通してそのままavdec_g722と問題なく音声は再生されたのでavdec_g722のエレメント自体は問題なく動作はしている？気はしています。